# How can i upload documentation to pythonhosted.org

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pypi

I've been struggling for a long time to upload some documentation online but all my attempt has been a waste. I've read so many guides but they still do not help. I've zipped the file but get errors when manual]y uploading but the PyPI website says `index.html` can't be found even though its there. I've  also tried the sphinx upload package but do not really get it to work successfully.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. PyPI help guides doesn't help either.

This is how my folder is structured

```
Eventsim
 |__ build
 |__ dist
 |__ doc
 |__ eventsim
 |__ setup.py
 |__ readme
   |__ _build
   |  |__ html
   |  |  |__ index.html
   |  |  |__ all htmlfiles etc.
   |  |__ doctrees
   |__ _static
   |__ _templates
   |__ conf.py
   |__ index.rst
   |__ make.bat
   |__ etc
```

the `doc` contains all `sphinx` data
i once made a `setup.cfg` and it built well but uploading was a fatal error.

Comment: what command you perform to upload and what error it shows

Comment: and what's the content of your setup.cfg?

Comment: Also see: https://readthedocs.org/ (often friendlier if you host your open source package source code in Github, Bitbucket, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, I finally got it working. Actually i didn't need to go through all the steps I mentioned before. All i was expected to do was create an empty zip file and move the contents of my build/html into that zip file and upload. As for readthedocs, i will try that option too  Thanks a lot people

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/WoLpH/sphinx-pypi-upload/

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/672

Comment: An earlier version of the script mentioned above: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx-PyPI-upload/0.2.1